# Trouble with functions in python 2.7.3

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I am new to learning python, and I only have limited programing experience, so I am sorry for asking such a basic question. I am doing an online python tutorial and wanted to take the program a bit further than the lesson requested to test out how far I could take it. The problem is that I have been hitting a roadblock. After reading a bunch of posts on here I have moved things around, changed variable names, used more functions, less functions, if else statements, and toyed around/ troubleshot, but have received all sorts of errors. I am going to paste where I currently am at below and would really appreciate if someone out there could help me finish up the program.

Here is what I would like for the program to do:

- I would like the user to be prompted to enter a number.
- I would like to make sure that the user entered a number, and if they don't I would like the program to give them an error and restart.
- I would like that once the number is received the program squares that number and then prints the answer.
  (again thanks much for all the help)

HERE IS WHERE I AM AT:

```
n1 = raw_input('Please enter your desired number:')

def n2():

    n2 = n1.isnumeric()

    return n2

def square(n2):

    squared = n2**2
    print "%d squared is %d." % (n2, squared)
    return squared    

square(n2)
```

Comment: What kind number would you get `only int ` or both `int and float`

Comment: I guess it could be either one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n2 = raw_input("number pls\n")
while not n2.isdigit():
      print("why did you do this\n")
      n2 = raw_input("number pls\n")

print int(n2)**2
```

Problems from your code:
You need a control structure which repeatedly tries to do something until the right thing happens.  This should make you think "while loop."

isnumeric isn't a method.  but you had the right idea.

Naming all of your variables and functions n2 is not a good way to easily see what's going on..

If you want to add a construct for floats, you should write a function which takes a string in and returns true or false based on if it looks like a float!  This is a good example for using functions to decompose the problem you're working with- you know you need to do something like

`while not (n2.isdigit or isFloat(n2)):`

There are some good suggestions here and elsewhere about how to do that  :)

Comment: I will mess around with it later.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if you could convert into `float`   if so print the square else print the error .To repeat this process while you get a number you could use `while` loop

```
def number_validator( numb ):    
    try:
        float( numb )
        return True
    except Exception:
        print "GIven input is not a valid number"
        return False

def square( n2 ):
    n2=float( n2 )
    squared = n2**2
    print "%s squared is %s." % ( n2 , squared )

    return squared    
n2 = raw_input( 'Please enter your desired number:' )
while not number_validator( n2 ):
    n2 = raw_input( 'Please enter your desired number:' )

square( n2 )
```

**Output:**

```
Please enter your desired number:wq
GIven input is not a valid number

Please enter your desired number:we
GIven input is not a valid number

Please enter your desired number:21.0
21.0 squared is 441.0.
```

Comment: I will mess around with it later, see if I can get everything to work